# Cuda::Entry function shared data

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

Does anybody know why the following function, uses 16,432 B of shared data?
In my opinion it should be: 2 x 32 x 32 x 8 B = 16,384 B

```
__global__ void matrixMulKernel(double *c, const double *a, const double *b, unsigned int size)
{
    __shared__ double as[32][32];
    __shared__ double bs[32][32];
    unsigned int bx = blockIdx.x, by = blockIdx.y;
    unsigned int tx = threadIdx.x, ty = threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int row = bx * TILE_WIDTH + tx;
    unsigned int col = by * TILE_WIDTH + ty;
    double Pval = 0.0;
    for(unsigned int q = 0; q < size / TILE_WIDTH; q++)
    {
        as[tx][ty] = a[row * size + q * TILE_WIDTH + ty];
        bs[ty][tx] = b[(q * TILE_WIDTH + tx) * size + col];
        __syncthreads();
        
        for(unsigned int k = 0; k < TILE_WIDTH; k++)
            Pval += as[tx][k] * bs[k][ty];
        __syncthreads();
    }

    c[row * size + col] = Pval;
}
```

The compiler is giving following error:

```
Entry function '_Z15matrixMulKernelPdPKdS1_j' uses too much shared data (0x4030 bytes, 0x4000 max)
```

I'm interested in why this is so, not as a workaround :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are compiling for a cc 1.x device.  The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-parameters) indicates that global kernel parameters are passed via shared memory for cc 1.x devices.

So you have 16,384 bytes for your explicit `__shared__` declarations.
The remainder would be from the 28 bytes (assuming 64 bit target) required by your explicit kernel parameters plus other overhead that is communicated via shared memory.

Try compiling for a cc 2.x device:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 ...
```

Comment: Thank you Robert. I already compiled for nvcc -arch=sm_30. I was just curious why it works like this. Regards